# Passing function arguments in react-native-boilerplate

Tags: react-native, immutable.js

I'm learning React Native and am creating a practice app using [React Native Boilerplate](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-boilerplate). I'm trying to pass arguments from a component through to a reducer, but after trying everything I can think of, I am still unable to do so. I'll use the unchanged boilerplate's Counter component as an example.

My current solution has this and works fine:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={increment}>
<Text style={styles.text}>+</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

However, I want to pass arguments, which would look like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={increment(argument)}>
<Text style={styles.text}>+</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The latter doesn't work. The function is undefined. My containers, actions, and reducers are in the same format as they appear in the sample app. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={(argument)=>increment(argument)}>
```

Use an arrow function to add a parameter to the call

Comment: Yep, that did it! Wow, I came so close yesterday. Looks like I used `()=>increment(argument)`, which (looking at it with fresh eyes after a full night's rest) doesn't make a great deal of sense...